# I can't figure out how to separate variables in this differential equation;

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

\begin{align*}
xyy'^2 + (x^2 + y^2)y' + xy = 0 \\
\end{align*}

I tried doing all kinds of things to separate the x and dx on one side and y and dy on the other and none of it worked. I'd post my attempts but I don't think you'd get anything from them since they don't go very far. Am I missing something? This is in the part of the textbook with basic differential equations, so it shouldn't require any specific methods, as far as I know.

Comment: one solution is $y=\frac{C}{x}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $y'=t$

we get

$t^2 x y+t \left(x^2+y^2\right)+x y=0$

Which is a quadratic algebraic equation in $t$

Solve and get

$$t_1=-\frac{x}{y};\;t_2=-\frac{y}{x}$$
This means two differential equations

$$y'=-\frac{x}{y};\;y'=-\frac{y}{x}$$
separate variables like this

$$ydy=-xdx;\;\frac{dy}{y}=-\frac{dx}{x}$$
and get two sets of solutions

$$\frac{y^2}{2}=-\frac{x^2}{2}+C_1\to x^2+y^2=2C_1\to x^2+y^2=C$$

$$\log y=-\log x +C\to \log y=\log \frac{k}{x} \to y=\frac{k}{x}$$
$$x^2+y^2=C;\;y=\frac{k}{x}$$
Hope this is useful

Comment: I understand and have solved it for myself now, since I'm new to differential equations, I haven't thought of doing it this way yet, which is kind of embarrassing since it looks so obvious now, but at least now I'll know what to look for.
However, I'm wondering why you're choosing to write $x^2+y^2 = C$ that way, and not as $y = -x + c$? It might be just notation but if there's a pragmatic reason, I'd like to know.
Also, I'm not entirely sure what k in $y = \frac{k}{x}$ is meant to be. I got $y = \frac{1}{x} + c$. Is that what it represents? Why k, though? Thanks.

Comment: @Robo I have added a few lines. It should be clearer now... Remember that for the propertty of logarithms $$\log\frac{1}{x}+C$$ can be written as $$\log\frac{1}{x}+\log k=\log \frac{k}{x}$$

Answer (score 2):

Solving the equation for $y’$, we have: $$y’=\frac{-(x^2+y^2) \pm (x^2-y^2)}{2xy}$$ that gives us: $y’= -\frac{y}{x}$ and $y’=-\frac{x}{y}$.

Hope you can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

write your equation in the form
$$y'^2+\left(\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}\right)y'+1=0$$ and set $$y=ux$$